# IIS Express system tray menu slow to launch site

Tags: iis-express

I'm using IIS Express 8 on Windows 7, building an MVC 4 application withVS 2012. I've just switched to a new PC, and there's a strange problem with the IIS System Tray menu on the new PC.

[image: IIS Express System Tray]

Launching the debugger is quick and the IIS Express icon appears quickly, and if I request the URL from a browser it's quick, but if I click on the menu item shown above, it takes about 60 seconds before the HTTP request is sent.

Why would this take so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express sys-tray just do Process.Start with URL and that in turn launches the default browser. May be launching the first instance of default browser takes that time. Try starting the browser first and then click link on the sys-tray menu, hopefully it would be fast.

Comment: I've tried launching the default browser (IE unfortunately) and opening the link from there, and it's fine. Launching IE and then clicking the systray menu item is still hideously slow though, so there seems to be something getting in the way of the menu item.

Comment: The problem actually seems to be launching IE from the menu item, or any other process. Still haven't got to the bottom of it though!